# Viewing just one div from an html page

Tags: html, firefox-extensions

I am speaking from the perspective of the end-user. Suppose I am visiting a website, which has a log divs. Most of them are displaying ads, menus, etc. but one of them is displaying the main content of the page.

Is there a way, in which I the user, using my browser, or some other tools such as Firebug etc, can view just that one div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you could use [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) to write a script for that particular website, essentially modifying the HTML on the fly. [This](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/78214) seems to be similar example.

Answer (score 1):

To add on to @erikxiv's suggestion to use [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) and JavaScript, I sought out a specific solution to your example. I asked the community over at StackOverflow for some help and [jfriend00](https://stackoverflow.com/users/816620/jfriend00)'s answer works great: [Set `display: none` recursively except for within a specific element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10218377/set-display-none-recursively-except-for-within-a-specific-element)